# Is it possible to defer initialization of a const variable in C++, like Java's "blank final" feature?

Tags: java, c++, c++11, constants, final

In Java we can declare a [blank `final`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.4) variable and initialize it later. The compiler will ensure initialization happens *exactly once* -- failure to initialize or double-initialization are both compile-time errors. For example:

```java
public int bar() {
   return 66;
}

public void foo() {
    final int x; // declare the variable
    ...
    x = bar(); // initialization only once
}
```

In Java, the compiler can guarantee that `x` is definitely not assigned on any code path prior to its first assignment, and can guarantee that it is definitely never assigned a second time on any code path. (See [Chapter 16, *Definite Assignment*, of the Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-16.html) for more information.)

How can we achieve similar behavior in C++? Is it possible to have a variable declared `const` but defer its initialization? (Without casting away the `const` specifier.)

Comment: Why not refactor the code to `...
       int x = 0; // declare the variable and initialization only once`?

Comment: @NathanOliver no, just assume want this behavior , declare else where and initialize somewhere but same scope, how can we emulate this on C++?

Comment: @NathanOliver: Because you might have two different code branches that each initialize the variable, and you want the compiler to guarantee that it's initialized exactly once. (No code path skips assigning a value, and no code path assigns twice.) To the best of my knowledge, C++ has nothing that corresponds to this Java feature.

Comment: @Buddhika: I'm not a C++ expert, so I can't say for sure, but I think this hinges on another feature that Java has and C++ doesn't: reading from an uninitialized variable is *guaranteed* to be a *compile-time error* in Java, whereas it's *undefined behavior* in C++.

Comment: @DanielPryden I am totally agree with you, but Daniel ,Oliver , don't we have any other option or alternative to achieve this in C++?

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux ,thanks for the reply, don't misunderstand I got those points already, what I wanted to perform is get the exact behavior of Java's blank final variable, I know we cannot match two different language design and its features,but I tried to map this behavior into C++.

Comment: There is no way to get a C++ compiler to perform compile-time flow analysis that prevents a variable from being assigned twice, so perfect emulation of this Java feature is not possible. However, in some types of situations where you would use a blank final variable in Java, you may be able to write something similar in C++. That's part and parcel of learning a new programming language. If you explain what you are trying to do, it might be possible for people to suggest a C++ solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C++ doesn't have a built in feature for this.  You can kind of build it for yourself though.  You can create a class that holds storage for an object of the type you want and you can overload the assignment operator for that so it can only be called and initialized once.  That would look like

```
template<typename T>
class once
{
private: 
    std::aligned_storage_t<sizeof(T), alignof(T)> data;
    T* ptr = nullptr;
public:
    once() = default;
    ~once()
    {
        if(ptr) // it is initialized so call the destructor
            ptr->~T();
        // optionally you can add
        // throw("a once<T> must be initialized once");
        // this can help to enforce that the object is actually initialized as you'll get a runtime exception in code that does not do so
    }
    template<typename U>
    once& operator =(U&& value)
    {
        if (!ptr) // it is not initialized so call constructor
        {
            ptr = new(&data) T(std::forward<U>(value));
        }
        else
            throw ("can only assign to a once<T> once.");
        return *this;
    }
    operator const T&()
    {
        return *ptr;
    }

};
```

and then you would use it like

```
int main()
{
    once<int> foo;
    if (1 < -1)
        foo = 21;
    else
        foo = 42;
    std::cout << foo;
    //foo = 23; // uncomment this to get an exception.
}
```

Comment: This "works" but it throws an exception at runtime instead of causing a compile-time error. It would be interesting to see if it were possible to do some kind of template magic to make this fail at compile time. (I suspect it's impossible, but it would be cool if it could be done.)

Comment: @DanielPryden Unfortunately I don't think that can be done since you need to modify the state of the object.  Who knows though.  C++ has a lot of "hidden" features that can do some really fun stuff so someone might come up with something.

Comment: You can assign T instead of throw. I would make the assignment a template or at least provide the rvalue version as well. Also the return of assignment had better be reference to contained T.  PS: The destructor is missing too.

Comment: @Red.Wave Good suggestion on making it a template.  I've added that using a forwarding reference.  I've also added the destructor so it will work for non trivial types.  I'm leaving the exception in there as a silent assignment can be hard to debug, while the exception will pop up on the first run.

Comment: You can avoid that rather ugly (and illegal?) cast by assigning the result of your placement `new` to a member variable of type `T *`.  Indeed, if you initialise this variable to `nullptr` then you can get rid of `first`.

Comment: @PaulSanders Great idea.  The cast isn't illegal (`std::launder` makes it defined behavior) but this looks so much better.  Thanks.

Comment: The const qualifier however is a pain in the neck.

Answer (score 4):

It's not possible to initialize a const except where it's defined. You have to find a way to know it's value where it's defined. If `x`'s value is difficult to determine, consider using the result of a function like

```
const int x = calc_x();
```

or a closure like

```
const int x = []() { /* code to calculate x's value */ }();
```

`const`ness is part of the type of an object and an object type's cannot be changed under any circumstance, therefore either `x` is `const` and you can't initialize it later or `x` is not `const` at all.

It's possible to design a wrapper `class` that would emulate this, but you would at best get a run-time error.

Note that there may seem to be solution in the form of `const_cast` but that assumes that the object in question is not actually `const`. In the case of `const int x` there is no way to legally change it's value after it's initialization.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Francois, thanks for this one :- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/launder

Comment: @Buddhika It was actually a mistake to mention `launder` in the first place. It might look like it could be used to change `x` but `x` becomes unusable after you've replaced it with another constant. I've removed it from my answer.